# In FSCalendar, how to refresh minimum date without reloadData

Tags: fscalendar

I am implementing calendar using FSCaleder in which 3 single dates are selected. Every date becomes minimum date for next date. To trigger update of minimum date, I am calling [FSCalendar reloadData] which is causing unintended scroll if minimum date in another month. 
I want to avoid automatic scrolling after change of minimum date.

Is there any approach to update minimum date without calling reloadData method